`matplotlib` figure text automatically adjusting position to the corners with multiple axes in the figure
This question address how to put text in the top left corner, higher than everything else in the figure, left of everything else in the figure.
Now I want text in all four corners, and I want to do it with multiple plots within a single figure (something like fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 3)).
Top left is higher and to the left of everything else in the figure (except for these four annotations).
Top right is higher and to the right of everything else in the figure (except for these four annotations).
Bottom left is lower and to the left of everything else in the figure (except for these four annotations).
Bottom right is lower and to the right of everything else in the figure (except for these four annotations).
Just adjusting the accepted answer to go to the bottom or to the right of the corresponding axes is not working.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 3)
ax[0, 0].scatter([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
yl = ax[0, 0].set_ylabel("1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7")
t = ax[0, 0].set_title("a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf")
ax[0, 0].annotate(
    "ABCD", 
    (0, 1),
    ha="right",
    va="bottom",
    color = 'red',
    xycoords=(yl, t)
)
ax[1, 2].annotate(
    "EFGH",
    (1, 0),
    ha="left",
    va="top",
    xycoords=(yl, t)
)
ax[1, 0].annotate(
    "IJKL",
    (0, 0),
    ha = "right",
    va = "bottom",
    xycoords=(t, yl)
)
ax[0, 2].annotate(
    "MNOP",
    (1, 1),
    ha="right",
    va="top",
    xycoords=(yl, t)
)
fig.patch.set_linewidth(5)
fig.patch.set_edgecolor("green")
plt.savefig(
    "test.png",
    dpi = 900,
    bbox_inches = "tight",
    edgecolor = fig.get_edgecolor()
)
plt.show()
plt.close()


What would be the correct syntax to do to the above plot (to all four corners) what the accepted answer here does for the top left corner?

it seems you have to use different objects in xycoords to put text in other corners.

if you use plt.figtext(...) then you can put text in corners of fig. If you correct va, ha then text can be outside fig - but it may need to add some margins to see this text

python - How to put text outside of plots - Stack Overflow

other idea: I never test it but figure can have subfigures - so you could put all plots as subfigure and draw text in main figure, and probably it should be outside all plots. See example in matplotlib doc: Figure subfigures — Matplotlib 3.9.0 documentation

or you could create figure with 9 subfigures (3x3) and put plots in subfigure [1,1] and text in subfigures [0,0], [2,0], [0,2], [2,2]. But problem is that every subfigure use the same size of space - so text will have too much space.

you can try xycoords=fig in annotate() and it will put in corners but not exactly outside other elements.

@furas I'm astounded that there seems not to be an obvious way to determine the coordinates of the entire figure and then work in terms of those coordinates.

well, maybe nobody needed. But using xycoords=fig you can put text in corners - only problem is that it doesn't resize margins as much as you probably need. It would need own system for layout calculations - and this can be complex task.

or maybe you should use subplots or subfigures to create grid 3x3 and put all plots in center cell of grid, and text put in corners cells of this grid. This is how I would do if it would be HTML - I would create table 3x3
